# Why am I getting this NullPointerException while trying to assign images to my GridView?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have a GridView to which different images associated with instances of an object are applied. I'm using a RealPathUtil object to handle the retrieval of file paths for decoding and displaying bitmaps.

When I open the activity in which these images are assigned to the grid, my application automatically crashes and shows a NullPointerException directed at the line where this if clause is declared:

```
else if ("content".equals(uri.scheme!!, ignoreCase = true)) {
       // Return the remote address
       return if (isGooglePhotosUri(uri)) uri.lastPathSegment else getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null)
}
```

I'm familiar with NullPointerExceptions and why they're typically thrown, but I don't really understand why this one is being given. None of the images that I'm trying to assign are even displaying properly since I switched the image display method from URI to Bitmap. When I was assigning images to ImageViews using URIs, this issue didn't come up, but I had to switch because that was giving issues on other devices.

Here's the code, from the adapter that handles the GridView, that is causing this error to come up. The error occurs from when the value of tempUri is set toward the end:

```
override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {
        val view: View = View.inflate(activity,R.layout.layout_adapter,null)

        // Get view data from UI elements - image, name, and count
        val tv_lang = view.findViewById(R.id.itemName) as TextView
        val imageView = view.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.itemImage)
        val itemCount = view.findViewById(R.id.itemCount) as TextView

        // Assign data to UI elements
        tv_lang.text = itemList[position].itemNote
        itemCount.text = itemList[position].itemCount.toString()
        val itemImage = itemList[position].itemImage


        // Assign each item image to corresponding grid ImageView
        tempUri = Uri.parse(itemImage)
        realPathUri = RealPathUtil.getRealPath(parent!!.context, tempUri).toString()
        val myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(realPathUri)
        imageView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap)

        return view
}
```

**RealPathUtil**

```
    object RealPathUtil {
        // SDK <= 11 && SDK < 19
        /* Calls either getRealPathFromURIAPI11to19 or getRealPathFromURIAPI19, depending upon which API the software detects the user running the app through. */
        @SuppressLint("ObsoleteSdkInt")
        fun getRealPath(context: Context, fileUri: Uri): String? {
            return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) {
                getRealPathFromURIAPI11to18(context, fileUri)
            } else {
                getRealPathFromURIAPI19(context, fileUri)
            }
        }

        /* Uses other methods within the RealPathUtil object to determine
        * location list file path based upon the user's phone's active API (11-18). */
        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        fun getRealPathFromURIAPI11to18(context: Context, contentUri: Uri): String? {
            val project = arrayOf(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA)
            var result: String? = ""

            val cursorLoader = CursorLoader(context, contentUri, project, null, null, null)
            val cursor = cursorLoader.loadInBackground()

            if (cursor != null) {
                val columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA)
                cursor.moveToFirst()
                result = cursor.getString(columnIndex)
                cursor.close()
            }
            return result
        }

        /* Uses other methods within the RealPathUtil object to determine location list file
        path based upon the user's phone's active API (19). */
        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        fun getRealPathFromURIAPI19(context: Context, uri: Uri): String? {
            val isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT

            // Create the DocumentProvider
            if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {
                // Safe cast the ExternalStorageProvider
                if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
                    val docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri)
                    val split = docId.split(":".toRegex()).dropLastWhile { it.isEmpty() }.toTypedArray()
                    val type = split[0]

                    if ("primary".equals(type, ignoreCase = true)) {
                        return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + split[1]
                    }
                } else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {
                    var cursor: Cursor? = null

                    try {
                        cursor = context.contentResolver.query(uri, arrayOf(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME), null, null, null)
                        cursor!!.moveToNext()

                        val fileName = cursor.getString(0)
                        val path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Download/" + fileName

                        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(path)) {
                            return path
                        }
                    } finally {
                        cursor?.close()
                    }

                    val id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri)

                    if (id.startsWith("raw:")) {
                        return id.replaceFirst("raw:".toRegex(), "")
                    }
                    val contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Uri.parse("content://downloads"), java.lang.Long.valueOf(id))

                    return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null)
                } else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
                    val docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri)
                    val split = docId.split(":".toRegex()).dropLastWhile { it.isEmpty() }.toTypedArray()
                    val type = split[0]

                    var contentUri: Uri? = null

                    when (type) {
                        "image" -> contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
                        "video" -> contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
                        "audio" -> contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
                    }

                    val selection = "_id=?"
                    val selectionArgs = arrayOf(split[1])

                    return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs)
                } // Media Provider
                // Downloads Provider
            } else if ("content".equals(uri.scheme!!, ignoreCase = true)) {
                // Return the remote address
                return if (isGooglePhotosUri(uri))
                    uri.lastPathSegment
                else
                    getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null) /** Collapse this if-else block into one line if any new, unexplained I/O issues arise. */
            } else if ("file".equals(uri.scheme!!, ignoreCase = true)) {
                return uri.path
            } // File
            // MediaStore

            return null
        }

        private fun getDataColumn(context: Context, uri: Uri?, selection: String?, selectionArgs: Array<String>?): String? {
            var cursor: Cursor? = null
            val column = "_data"
            val projection = arrayOf(column)

            try {
                cursor = context.contentResolver.query(uri!!, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null)

                if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    val index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column)
                    return cursor.getString(index)
                }
            } finally {
                cursor?.close()
            }
            return null
        }

        /* Takes the URI being analyzed and determines whether the URI authority is ExternalFileProvider or not. */
        private fun isExternalStorageDocument(uri: Uri): Boolean {
            return "com.android.externalstorage.documents" == uri.authority
        }

        /* Takes the URI being analyzed and determines whether the URI authority is DownloadsProvider or not. */
        private fun isDownloadsDocument(uri: Uri): Boolean {
            return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents" == uri.authority
        }

        /* Takes the URI being analyzed and determines whether the URI authority is MediaProvider or not. */
        private fun isMediaDocument(uri: Uri): Boolean {
            return "com.android.providers.media.documents" == uri.authority
        }

        /* Takes the URI being analyzed and determines whether the URI authority is Google Photos or not. */
        private fun isGooglePhotosUri(uri: Uri): Boolean {
            return "com.google.android.apps.photos.content" == uri.authority
        }
    }
```

I understand this has to do with how the path is being retrieved, but I don't really know how. I've been using this object for a long time and I've never run into an issue like this, so I don't really know where to start debugging. I'm not asking for a solution to my problem, but if some astute person with more experience than me could tell me where this issue is coming from, I might be able to figure it out. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the `if` clause you're referring to is this one:

> ```
> else if ("content".equals(uri.scheme!!, ignoreCase = true)) {
> ```

The obvious place for a NullPointerException here is `uri.scheme!!`. The double-bang operator is used to *assert* that a variable with a nullable type is not, in fact, `null`, and to retrieve its value. This is sometimes useful when we, as humans, know more than the compiler does... but it is also possible for humans to be wrong!

If `uri.scheme` is null, then `uri.scheme!!` will throw a NullPointerException.

How to solve this depends on the rest of your program. Perhaps you don't expect `uri.scheme` to ever be null, in which case you'd have some deeper root cause to figure out. But if you *do* expect that `uri.scheme` might be null sometimes, you could rewrite your `if` condition:

```
else if (uri.scheme?.equals("content", ignoreCase = true) == true) {
```

Comment: Ben, thank you for answering this in such a concise and informative fashion - although the images I'm trying to get to display are still not displaying, this change stopped the NullPointerExceptions, and I have a better understanding of why they were coming up in the first place. At least now I can iron out the image display issue without crashing from that every time I try to open the related activity :P

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to check Null when using String.equals. check the code

```
public actual fun String?.equals(other: String?, ignoreCase: Boolean = false): Boolean { 
if (this === null) 
    return other === null
return if (!ignoreCase) (this as java.lang.String).equals(other) 
       else (this as java.lang.String).equalsIgnoreCase(other) 
}
```